# Linux crashes after resume from suspend

Tags: linux, suspend, freeze, crash

My Linux crashes after it wakes up from sleep mode,
namely, it stops responding to any commands,
at the moment I have Manjaro Linux, but there was a similar problem on Ubuntu.

My laptop: Huawei Mate Book D16 RLEF-X with processor: Intel i5-12450H.

I tried to change the value of some parameter in the `root/etc/default/grub` file, but it didn't help me, Everything ends in the logs when entering sleep mode.
I have heard that a similar problem manifests itself on many (if not all) laptops of this model and the Huawei brand in particular. But maybe there is some solution to this problem?

```
сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx systemd-logind[418]: The system will suspend now!

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517238.9251] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx ModemManager[443]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517238.9253] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517238.9257] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517238.9258] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx dbus-daemon[416]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=0 pid=419 comm="/usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon")

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx kded5[741]: org.kde.plasma.nm.kded: Unhandled active connection state change:  3

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx dbus-daemon[416]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.

сен 24 04:00:38 artyom-rlefxx kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from e2:c7:58:19:a6:a9 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx kscreenlocker_greet[4371]: Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e2:c7:58:19:a6:a9 reason=3 locally_generated=1

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1169] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1170] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1172] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1172] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1172] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1517] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 26:D7:AB:DA:5A:BF (scanning)

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.1803] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx NetworkManager[419]: <info>  [1695517239.2016] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 30:05:05:98:BC:E6 (unmanage)

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx kscreenlocker_greet[4371]: kf.kirigami: Failed to find a Kirigami platform plugin

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx wpa_supplicant[499]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx kscreenlocker_greet[4371]: qt.virtualkeyboard.hunspell: Hunspell dictionary is missing for "en_US" . Search paths ("/usr/share/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/hunspell", "/usr/share/hunspell", "/usr/share/myspell/dicts")

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx systemd-sleep[4409]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...

сен 24 04:00:39 artyom-rlefxx kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found. After many days of trying and suffering, I finally decided to install POP OS! and check its operation on this problematic unit. After coming out of sleep mode in the new system, lo and behold, the system was still working. But it was too early to rejoice, she switched to reading mode. It was impossible to perform any action with memory. Then I realized the problem is in the SSD NVMe drive, which is from the factory in the laptop. He was the reason for the incorrect operation of any Linux distribution. This drive simply did not "wake up" after coming out of sleep mode. Various methods have been tried to correct this error, but to no avail. Only the replacement of the regular strange SSD with a normal new one helped . I really hope that anyone who bought this laptop and encountered a similar error will find this post and will finally be able to install this wonderful system on their laptop :)